# Requiero seleccionar los precios máximos, mínimos, precio de apertura y el precio de cierre de cada proveedor

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

La tabla está estructuarada en el siguiente enlaze (uso MySQL)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8341c

Nota: se puede tener más de un registro del mismo proveedor del mismo día pero con diferente hora,
la hora que se considera apertura es a las 00:00:00 y la hora de cierre es a las 23:59:59

hasta ahora tengo esto que me produce lo siguiente:

```
    SELECT t1.name as 'Name',t1.min as 'MinCost',t1.max as 'MaxCost',t2.open ,t3.close,t1.times as 'Date'
  FROM(
        select name, max(cost) as 'max',min(cost) as 'min', date(time) as 'times'  
        from providers 
        group by  times,name 
        order by times
   ) AS t1
   JOIN (
     select name,cost as 'open',  time  
     from providers 
     where TIME(time) = '00:00:00'   
     group by time,name
     order by time
   ) as t2 on t1.name=t2.name
   JOIN (
       select name,cost as 'close', time  
       from providers 
       where TIME(time) = '23:59:59'   
       group by time,name
       order by time
   ) as t3 on t2.name=t3.name 
   GROUP BY t1.times,t1.name
   ORDER BY t1.times,t1.name
   ;

| Name | MinCost | MaxCost | open | close |       Date |
|------|---------|---------|------|-------|------------|
|  ABC |    13.6 |    15.3 | 14.1 |  14.2 | 2015-12-02 |
|  DEF |    93.2 |    96.3 | 97.7 |  95.4 | 2015-12-02 |
|  ABC |    15.1 |    15.6 | 14.1 |  14.2 | 2015-12-03 |
|  DEF |    97.2 |    97.7 | 97.7 |  95.4 | 2015-12-03 |
```

el output esperado con los datos del sql fiddle sería:

```
Name|MinCost |MaxCost | Open | Close | Date
ABC |13.6    | 15.3   | 14.1 | 14.2  | 2015-12-02
DEF |93.2    | 96.3   | 93.7 | 95.4  | 2015-12-02 
ABC |15.1    | 15.6   | 15.1 | 15.2  | 2015-12-03
DEF |97.2    | 97.7   | 97.4 | 97.7  | 2015-12-03
```

Comment: Bienvenido, le falta mucho a tu pregunta como una muestra de los datos de entrada y como deseas que se vean a la salida, además de eso que consulta has tratado y donde tienes fallos

Comment: Estaría bien tener también un ejemplo de datos de entrada y el resultado que necesitas obtener.

Comment: Mi pregunta está actualizada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.fecha,
       t1.name,
       t1.MinCost,
       t1.MaxCost,
       t3.cost    as close,
       t2.cost    as open
       from (select  name,
                     date(time) as fecha,
                     min(cost)  as MinCost,  
                     max(cost)  as MaxCost,
                     max(time) as close,
                     min(time) as open
                     from providers
                     group by date(time),
                              name
        ) t1
        inner join providers t2
          on t2.name = t1.name
          and t2.time = t1.open
        inner join providers t3
          on t3.name = t1.name
          and t3.time = t1.close
       group by t1.fecha,
                t1.name,
                t1.MinCost,
                t1.MaxCost,
                t2.cost,
                t3.cost;
```

Detalle:

- La subconsulta interior retorna `MinCost` y `MaxCost`, pero además las fechas de apertura y cierre
- Para obtener los valores de apertura y cierre deberemos hacer `joins` nuevamente a la tabla `providers` para obtener las mismas.

Comment: excelente y elegante solución, gracias, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Consulta por dia es un query bastante extenso asi que entrego las dos primeras columnas,
para max y min es mas sensillo el query

```
 SELECT
    tApertura.name,
    tApertura.cost as CostoApertura,
    tCierres.cost as CostoCierre,
    tApertura.dia as Dia
 FROM 
    (select day(p.time) dia,p.name,p.cost from Providers P 
   join (select min(time) tabre, name from providers
          group by day(time), name) as papertura
    on p.name=papertura.name
  and papertura.tabre=p.time) as tApertura
join
 (select day(p.time) dia,p.name,p.cost from Providers P 
   join (select max(time) tCierra, name from providers
          group by day(time), name) as pcerra
    on p.name=pcerra.name
  and pcerra.tCierra=p.time) as tCierres

on tApertura.name= tCierres.name
and   tApertura.dia=tCierres.dia
```

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo tu propio código, un pequeño cambio, y debería funcionar:

```
SELECT t1.name as 'Name',t1.min as 'MinCost',t1.max as 'MaxCost',t2.open ,t3.close,t1.times as 'Date'
  FROM(
        select name, max(cost) as 'max',min(cost) as 'min', date(time) as 'times'  
        from providers 
        group by  times,name 
        order by times
   ) AS t1
   JOIN (
     select name,cost as 'open',  time  
     from providers 
     where TIME(time) = '00:00:00'   
     group by time,name
     order by time
   ) as t2 on t1.name=t2.name and DATE(t1.time)=DATE(t2.time)
   JOIN (
       select name,cost as 'close', time  
       from providers 
       where TIME(time) = '23:59:59'   
       group by time,name
       order by time
   ) as t3 on t2.name=t3.name and DATE(t2.time)=DATE(t3.time) 
   GROUP BY t1.times,t1.name
   ORDER BY t1.times,t1.name
   ;
```